# EOP Quarantined emails

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365

Is it possible to configure Exchange Online Protection to send the quarantined emails report more than once a day? As per a Microsoft article which I'm not sure I'm allowed to post, the lowest value that you can set (in days) is 1, biggest being 15.

Is there any way that I can receive these reports more than once a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you need more frequent access to quarantine - consider Junk mail folder in Outlook instead. It offers a sandbox-like restricted view which is alike to quarantine, but the users will have an opportunity to

1. view the folder as frequently as they like
2. move the email to Inbox and open it.

There is an [idea on Office 365 user voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/289138-compliance-protection/suggestions/12882798-end-user-spam-notifacation-frequency) portal with the hint from MS that they probably won't do anything like this.